# AndroidでFHD（1080x1920）用のレイアウト

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

AndroidでFHD（1080x1920）用のレイアウトを作るにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？
問題となっているのはFHD+やQuad HD+とFHDのレイアウトを分けたいが、以下のようになってしまうことです。

試したことは以下です。
１． layout-w1080dp-h1920dp/hoge.xml を作ってFHD用のレイアウトを作成
→layout/hoge.xml が読み込まれる

2.values-w1080dp-h1920dp/dimens.xml を作ってFHD用の定義を作成
→values-sw360dp/dimens.xml が読み込まれる

開発環境等は以下です。
ツール：Android Studio

レイアウトファイル：
/res/layout/hoge.xml

dimensファイル
/res/values/dimens.xml
/res/values-sw360dp/dimens.xml
/res/values-sw600dp/dimens.xml
/res/values-sw720dp/dimens.xml

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

自己解決です。

プログラムで画面サイズを取得し、FHDであれば`setContentView`で別レイアウトを設定することで回避しました。